# correct typeguard for union object array iteration

Tags: arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

```
type A = ~~;
type B = ~~;
type C = ~~;

function isA(a: string) a is A{
   return a in A
}
```

I have three type or enum and I want to iterate array of U to make another array.

```
const arr1 = A|B|C[] // array that item's type is A|B|C
const arr2 = arr1.map(item=>{
   if(isA(item)){
     return {a: 1};
   }
   if(isB(item)){
      return {b:1};
   }
   if(isC(item)){
      return {c:1}
   }
}
```

IDE inferenced map value `item`  as  `A|B|C`  correctly

Problem is that when I do typeguard with if state, the result array item type contains 'undefined' type.

```
arr2 = ({a:1}|{b:1}|{c:1}|undefined)[]//like this
```

Anyway I could hint typescript that item does not contains undefined value??

Comment: You could throw an error after all the if statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a case where the predicate returns `undefined` (when `item` is not A, B, or C somehow):

```
const arr2 = arr1.map(item=>{
   if(isA(item)){
     return {a: 1};
   }
   if(isB(item)){
      return {b:1};
   }
   if(isC(item)){
      return {c:1}
   }
}
```

TS thinks it might return undefined. To assert that it shouldn't, you could throw an error:

```
const arr2 = arr1.map(item=>{
   if(isA(item)){
     return {a: 1};
   }
   if(isB(item)){
      return {b:1};
   }
   if(isC(item)){
      return {c:1}
   }
   throw new Error("Why did this happen?");
}
```

Now the return type is `A | B | C | never`, which simplifies to `A | B | C`.